# Get part of a file by byte number in php

Tags: php, file

How can I have php return just some bytes of a file? Like, it I wanted to load byte 7 through 15 into a string, without reading any other part of the file? Its important that I don't need to load all of the file into memory, as the file could be quite large.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');

// move to the 7th byte
fseek($fp, 7);

$data = fread($fp, 8);   // read 8 bytes from byte 7

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: ah-ha... I was going to post a slightly more unwieldy answer using `fread()` and `str_split()`. totally overlooked `fseek()`. this is much more succinct. thanks, must remember that in future!

Comment: Don't forget the comment in the help section if you're on Windows: On systems which differentiate between binary and text files (i.e. Windows) the file must be opened with 'b' included in fopen() mode parameter. (so `fopen('somefile.txt', 'rb')`

Answer (score 13):

Could use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) using the offset and maxlen parameters.

```
$data = file_get_contents('somefile.txt', false, NULL, 6, 8);
```

Comment: the second parameter should be `false` instead of `null` if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pear:

```
<?php
require_once 'File.php';

//read and output first 15 bytes of file myFile
echo File::read("/path/to/myFile", 15);
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/path/to/myFile";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, 15);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Either method you can use byte 7-15 to do what you want.  I don't think you can go after certain bytes without starting from the beginning of the file.