# How to extract data from CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm using the Sebastian Bergmann PHPUnit selenium webdriver.
Current I have:

```
$csv = file_get_contents('functions.csv', NULL,NULL,1);
var_dump($csv);
// select 1 random line here
```

This will load my CSV file and give me all possible data from the file.
It has multiple rows for example:

```
Xenoloog-FUNC/8_4980
Xylofonist-FUNC/8_4981
IJscoman-FUNC/8_4982
```

**Question:** How can I get that data randomly?
I just want to use 1 ( random) line of data.

Would it be easier to just grab 1 (random) line of the file instead of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array, then grab a random index from that array:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $csv);
$item = $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the offset and maxlen parameters to grab part of the file using file_get_contents. You could also use fseek after fopen to select part of a file. These functions both take numbers of bytes as arguments. This post has a little more information:

[Get part of a file by byte number in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529405/get-part-of-a-file-by-byte-number-in-php)

It may require some hacking to translate a particular row-index of a CSV file to a byte offset. You might need to generate and load a small meta-data file which contains a list of bytes-occupancies for each row of of CSV data. That would probably help.