# Get right delimiter CSV file php

Tags: php, csv, delimiter, fgetcsv

I need to read a CSV file that is not mine. So sometimes the delimiter will be a semicolon and an another time it will be a comma. So I need to find a way to know which one will be the right delimiter.
I use `fgetcsv` with a third parameter that is the delimiter.

My first option was to make a `fgets` and a `strpos` with semicolon and comma. But when I use `fgets` my cursor jump to the second line. And I need every line. So next to that I try to use `rewind` or `fseek` to go back to the beginning of my file. But the file is on read only mode and I can't rewind it.

My second option was to have 2 handles for only one file. I can't use this it take 2x more times. I want something clean and optimize.

How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you `rewind` a read-only stream? Regardless, using two handles you should be able to [just grab the first `n` bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529503/231316), where `n` is a guess based on the data where you think delimiters should be. Maybe grab the first 100 or 1,000, count both the `,` and the `;` and whichever has more assume is the delimiter. There shouldn't be too much of overhead in doing this since you're working on a very small string.

Comment: When I rewind it tell me that my stream is not seekable. How can I make my stream seekable ?

Comment: Are you opening it using `fopen($file, 'r')`? Is this a real file, or a "virtual file" such as something from a zip file?

Comment: I'm opening it with `fopen($file, 'r')`. It's a file that I take from the web.

Comment: First `fgetcsv` with a semicolon and see if it outputs an array with the expected amount of elements (columns). If not run `fgetcsv` again with comma as delimiter. If you cant rewind your stream, you might want to reopen it in case the first try doesnt return the expected amount of columns.

Comment: @PtrTon No other way to do that ? Because it gonna double the amount of time to run my script. Currently this is my only solution. Do you know why a file is seekable or not ?

Comment: _“I'm opening it with fopen($file, 'r'). It's a file that I take from the web”_ - so I am guessing that last part means, it is not actually a _file_, but an HTTP URL instead? Then you can indeed not rewind, the HTTP stream wrapper does not allow for that.

Comment: If CBroe is correct, then just download the file normally and fun `fopen` on that, you'll be able to rewind it then